# How to find intermediates in symlink recursion?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Is there a non-recursive `readlink -f` / `realpath` alternative, that outputs absolute symlink destinations? A more POSIX compatible solution is welcome as well.

I have a function block in my shell script as follows:

```
set FILES
# addFile adds a file to the FILES list. If file is a symlink,
# it will also find and add the destination.
addFile() {
    file="$1"
    # Check if file is already included in list
    echo "$FILES" | grep -q "$file" && return
    FILES="$FILES $file"
    if [ -L $file ]; then
        addFile $(realpath $file)
        #addFile $(readlink $file)
    fi
}
```

I'm using this function in a script which is collecting binary and library files from around the file system. But I foresee a problem in this code:

1. My first try I used `readlink`, but this returned symlink resolution paths relative to the `$file`, thus any actions performed on those paths fail. (Now commented out, but still in code) (See minor edit below)
2. After that, I used `realpath` instead, as suggested by `man readlink`. It almost works.

Now, the actions that I want to perform can work. However, in the final result I'm copying over all the binaries, libraries and symlinks in an initramfs. If there are any recursive symlinks, only the top level and the destination will be included, not the intermediate ones. Thus, breaking the symlink.

I've created a [fiddle](http://tpcg.io/5tNag7) to demonstrate the issue. `link-to-link1` points to `link1`, which points to `file1`. In the end result `link1` is missing and `link-to-link1` is broken.

### Edit; clarify the issue

When running the above function on the following set of symlinks:

```
# Contents of ~/test/src
file0
file1
link0 -> file0
link0.1 -> file0
link1 -> file1
link-to-link1 -> link1
```

With:

```
copy="link-to-link1 link0 link0.1"
for sf in $copy; do
    addFile ~/test/src/$sf
done;
cp -av $FILES ~/test/dst
```

You will find that only the 3 links from `$copy` and 2 files are copied. However, intermediate link `link1` is missing and `link-to-link1` is broken.

I would like the script to find `link1` as well. Keeping in mind that in the environment where this script is run, the location of files and symlinks have to be absolute.

#### Minor edit

Add [another fiddle](http://tpcg.io/RDiAXI) to demonstrate failing of relative paths, using `readlink`. Only the symlinks are copied and the destinations are missing.

Comment: Can you give an example and the output you want for that in the question? As an aside: consider using an associative array to store the list of files, since you're using bash.

Comment: @muru, Did you check the linked fiddle? I attached that as a longer example. If that on'e not clear enough, I'll try to make some adjustments.

Comment: I'm looking at it, but it's a) better for the post to be self-contained and b) we shouldn't have to parse whatever you did to create the state in addition to whatever you're going to do with that state. So it's better if you can describe the input and the output you want *in the question*.

Comment: Ok, will try to clarify the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand right, for the example given, you want `link1` for the file `link-to-link1`. That you can get using GNU `find`'s `-printf` and `%l`:

```
$ find . -type l -printf '%p -> %l\n'
./link0.1 -> file0
./link1 -> file1
./link0 -> file0
./link-to-link1 -> link1
```

---

Since the absolute path of `link1` is needed as the output for `/path/to/link-to-link1`, maybe `cd` to the directory containing `link-to-link1` and run `readlink`/`realpath` in succession:

```
(
cd "$(dirname "$file")"
realpath -s "$(readlink "$file")"
)
```

`realpath -s` does not resolve symbolic links, but will print the absolute path.

For example:

```
~ file=/tmp/foo/link-to-link1
~ (cd "$(dirname "$file")"; realpath -s "$(readlink "$file")")
/tmp/foo/link1
```

This will also work for links to absolute paths:

```
~ file=/tmp/foo/link2
~ ln -sfv /tmp/foo/link1 "$file"
'/tmp/foo/link2' -> '/tmp/foo/link1'
~ (cd "$(dirname "$file")"; realpath -s "$(readlink "$file")")
/tmp/foo/link1
```

Comment: `find`'s `printf` and `%l` is giving a relative link, just like `readlink`. The problem being, if the links are not in the `$PWD`, `addFile()` will try to add a non-existing file. Hence, I resorted to `realpath` for absolute names, but that one's recursive and missing intermediate links.

Comment: @Tim check the update